# How to display a the name of the user in a Facebook post

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this function which works fine :

```
  function testAPI() {
   FB.login(function(){
    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'I am going for a run.'},
    function(response){if (!response || response.error)
        {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Error occured';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'ok';
        }
    }  
    );
    }, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
  }
```

This posts a facebook post like this as you can see:

```
I am going for a run.
```

What I want to do is if the user is Mike Tyson, I want to post :

```
Mike Tyson is going for a run.
```

I did `{message: '{name} is going for a run.'}`
But it didn't work.

Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: The message the user them self have to type and you can't change it at all. So just have the user type in "Mike Tyson is going for a run" if that is what the user want to share

Comment: @WizKid I'm writing the message in JS as you can see.

Comment: Which is not allowed. The user didn't type it in them self

Comment: @WizKid. What do you mean by not allowed? This is working. I have sent several posts using that function.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ chapter 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it is working" does not mean it´s allowed. You are not allowed to prefill the message parameter, it MUST be 100% user generated: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ (2.3)

What you would want to use is called "Custom Stories": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph